# How to dymatically generate data of first column in a table using Kendo Ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have table that I am outputting using Kendo UI as below:

[image]

My desire outcome is to have the table with an extra column '#" which simply have as data 1,2,3,4, etc.

[image]

Below is my attempt to solve this problem, but it doesn't work i.e As you can see in the image the column '#' is blank: (Using a Template column and DataBound event)

```
  @(
    Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.CryptoViewModel.data)
            .Name("Crypto")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
        columns.Template("<span class='row-number'></span>").Title("#");
               
            columns.Bound(x => x.name).Title("Name")
.HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "crypto-header" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-text-left" });

            columns.Bound(x => x.symbol).Title("Symbol")
        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "crypto-header" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-text-left" });

            columns.Bound(x => x.quote.USD.price).Title("Price").Format("{0:c2}")
        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "crypto-header" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-text-left" });

        columns.Bound(x => x.circulating_supply).Title("Circulating Supply").Format("{0:n0}")
        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "crypto-header" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-text-left" });

        columns.Bound(x => x.max_supply).Title("Max Supply").Format("{0:n0}")
        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "crypto-header" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-text-left" });

            columns.Bound(x => x.last_updated).Title("Last Updated").Width(200)
        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "crypto-header" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-text-left" });
        })
        .Editable()
        .Filterable()
        .Sortable()
    .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("onDataBinding"))
        
)  

<script>
function onDataBinding() {
    var grid = $("#Crypto").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
  
    var i = 1;
    $(dataSource._data).each(function () {   
       $('table tr').find('td:first').html(i);
      //var rowLabel = grid.find(".row-number");
      //$(rowLabel).html(i)
      i++;
    });       
}
```

What are my missing to solve this problem ?

Comment: "...but it doesn't work." What doesn't work? What behavior are you seeing? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Just blank as shown in the image

Answer (score 0):

You're making a big mistake trying to change the widget's html directly. Never do that. The widgets renders the html dynamically very often, so your changes would be overriden.

The `dataBinding` event receives the data items in the first param, so you can change them before they are used in the grid:

```
function onDataBinding(e) {
    e.items.forEach((item, index) => item.row_counter = (index + 1));
}
```

Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/themes/6.2.0/default/default-ocean-blue.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.314/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="grid"></div>
  <script>
    $('#grid').kendoGrid({
      dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [{
          name: 'John'
        },{
          name: 'Jane'
        }]
      }),
      columns: [{
        field: 'row_counter'
      },{
        field: 'name'
      }],
      dataBinding: function(e) {
        e.items.forEach((item, index) => item.row_counter = (index + 1));
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/ifEKOpEd)

Comment: Thanks @DontVoteMeDown.  How can I pass my `CryptoViewModel` to the `data` array in the javascript?

Comment: @FokwaBest the focus here is the `onDataBinding` example and not the rest of the grid code. I made a javascript grid because you can't make a demo with Asp.net.